# Know which user logging into app depending on touchid in iOS

Tags: ios, touch-id

In my app I am trying to detect which user is trying to log in using touchId. Is there any mechanism which can help me distinguish between users depending on touch Ids of users.

Comment: I assume that you are only assuming 1 one user per device since touch id isn't really setup for multiple users on a single device.

Comment: Also, I don't think you can figure out which of the registered fingers was used to authenticate, in case you were thinking of that.

Comment: @Dancreek and NicolasMiari Thank you guys. Your answers are precise. I was trying to do something for which touchid is not intended.

Comment: @rookieCoder did you get solution of your problem? I want to check same into my app. Please help me if you get something.

Comment: @shilpa Yes I got answer. Basically you cannot distinguish between users based on there touchid's you can only check whether touchid is valid or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are only assuming 1 one user per device since touch id isn't really setup for multiple users on a single device.

Since you already know which device your app is running on there would be no need to get this information from TouchID.